# is it possible to use method channel to communicate between an android app and flutter module that is built and included as "aar"?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, aar

This guide talks about the method channels to talk between flutter and native android.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

I have generated 'aar' file for my flutter module and included the aar file in my native android app. Now when i click a button from my android app , I am launching my flutter module through FlutterActivity class in android.

Now my question is , how do i communicate further between the native android code and generated aar code ?

How do I write my flutter module so that when I generate the 'aar' file and include in my android app , I would be able to establish communication between them ?

Answer (score 1):

The guide you mentioned talk about platform channel and how to communicate ([Flutter side](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example-client) and [Android side](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation)).

In your case, to communicate between Flutter and Android, you need a `MethodChannel` in both sides.

When creating a MethodChannel, you'll have to provide a unique name (usually, your package domain name) to let the engine create a channel between your Flutter side and your Android side.

Flutter side:

```dart
class MyPlugin {
  static const _channel = MethodChannel("example.dev/plugin");

  Future<String> getHelloWorld() async {
    final message = await _channel.invokeMethod<String>("getHelloWorld");

    print(message);
    return message;
  }
}
```

Android side (Kotlin):

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(binding.binaryMessenger, "example.dev/plugin")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getHelloWorld") {
      result.success("Hello world!")
      return
    }
    result.notImplemented()
  }
}
```

`onMethodCall` is called on Android side when you call `invokeMethod` from Flutter side.
Note that you pass a string to `invokeMethod`, it will be available in Android side in `call.method`, as shown in above example.
When you need to pass additional arguments, you can do so with:

Flutter side:

```dart
// ...

int age = 42;
String message = "This is the way";

String answer = await _channel.invokeMethod<String>("getMessage", <String, Object>{
  "age": age,
  "message": message
});

print(answer);

// ...
```

Android side (Kotlin):

```dart
// ...

if (call.method == "getMessage") {
  if (!call.hasArgument("age") || !call.hasArgument("message")) {
    result.error("MissingArgumentError", "You must provide age and message parameters.", null)
    return
  }
  val age: Int = call.argument<Int>("age")!!
  val message: String = call.argument<String>("message")!!

  result.success("$message at $age years old")
  return
}

// ...
```

You can pass common types of data through a MethodChannel, [see list of supported types](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-java-tab#codec).

Similarly, you can use an `EventChannel` between both sides to emit events (aka Stream).

You'll find more details in the guide as it comes from the official documentation.